# jQuery Validate with appended form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've read the four related answers on SO, and they form the main part of the dynamic validation I'm trying here.

I have a form with some dynamic actions like add and remove a block (div) which contains user studies or experiences. Each block contains few elements that I need to validate.

The validation to the appended element works only if you focus and then submit the form, before that, if you don't focus on element for exemple "study_5" and submit the form, it will get submitted with no problems (even if it has the required tag)

Here is my JS :

```
var multiple_formation_max_fields = 10;
            var multiple_formation_wrapper = $(".multiple-formation");
            var multiple_formation_add_button = $(".add_formation");

            var x = {{ Auth::user()->candidate and Auth::user()->candidate->certifications->count() > 0 ? Auth::user()->candidate->certifications->count() + 1 : 1}};
            $(multiple_formation_add_button).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (x < multiple_formation_max_fields) {
                    x++;
                    $(multiple_formation_wrapper).append(
                        '<div class="sub-form">' +
                                                    // deleted unusfull code
                        '<div class="col-lg-6">' +
                        '<span class="pf-title">Établissement</span>' +
                        '<div class="pf-field">' +
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" required id="formation_establishment_'+x+'" placeholder="ISET, Esprit, .. " name="formation_establishment[]">' +
                        // deleted unusfull code
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>'
                    );
                }
                $('.date').dateDropper();
                $(".chosen").chosen();
                $('#formation_establishment_'+x).rules('add', {
                    'required': true
                });
                $('#form').validate();

            });
```

and the result as if I click on submit without focusing on the second element appended to form :
[image]

The first validated element works because it is mainly on page.
The second one didn't.
The third one works because I pressed submit while focusing in there.

Comment: You mention that you'd tried four solutions posted here on SO.  It's pointless to mention this without linking to them as we would have no other way to know which answers you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal operation of the jQuery Validate plugin:

1. *Initialize* plugin on your form **on page load** via the `.validate()` method.  Do **not** initialize the form (do not call the `.validate()` method) within a `click` handler.
2. Add rules to dynamically added form fields via the `.rules()` method.

You cannot do step 2 before step 1.

---

You are calling `.validate()` after `.rules()` and it's inside a `click` handler.   The `.validate()` method is the *initialization* of the plugin on your form and should only be called *once*, and when the page is loaded.

You can never call the `.rules()` method before initializing the form with `.validate()`.

So pull `.validate()` completely out of the `click` handler and only call it once within the document ready handler.